# EventDriven NodeJS App Architecture with Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, architecture

I have a general question about developing a Nodejs App with own lifecycles and events to track serveral activities globally.

### What do I need?

Any

- References
- Tips and Tricks
- Blueprints
- Frameworks

### Background

In have developed a backend with database, authentification and fileupload. I made that very pragmatic and it works fine. But now I want to develop a new better architecture, which is event driven to track activities and lifecycle hooks to init modules.

I was researching about Libs, which seems to be great, but I need to know, if I am on a right way.

Here is the recent backend, which I want to renew from core:

[@fractools/node](https://github.com/fractools/fractoolsnode)

### Goal

The Node needs to be more abstract and event driven to track activities more globally for the hole process.

I was thinking about a core module, which defines the basement for events and hooks which listen to the hole application process.

So other modules like database handling, or authentification etc can be wrapped onto it.

### My questions

How can I have a helper like a activity logger, which is listening through the hole app, so I dont need to import a logger in every single action? Is it possible? Does this make any sense?

### Example Case

Core module tracks database acivities:

System puts Data into Database, core listen to it, tracks it and pushs this information into a Logger, which uses a Database.

#### Issue

I stuck for example at one simple architecture thing:

If I have a Database Class, and I want the Core, which is an extended EventErmitter, listen to database actions, I cant have a logger inside Core, which uses database, because i cant reference those modules to eachother at once:

```js
// Core Module

const EventErmitter = require('events');
const Database = require('./database)';

module.exports = class Core extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.logger = new Database('Logger');

    this.on('mounted', () => {
      this.logger.put('instance mounted')
    });

    this.on('putData', () => {
      this.logger.put('dataPut')
    });

    this.emit('mounted');
  }
}

// Database Module
const Core = require('./core');
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb'); // Which database lib to use is not important yet

let core = new Core();

module.exports = class Database {
  constructor(name, options) {

    this.id = generateID();
    this.name = name;
    this.created = JSON.stringify(new Date()); // TODO doubled Quotes

    this.options = options || {};

    this.db = new PouchDB(name);
    core.emits('mounted')
  }
  put(data) {
    this.db.put(data);
    core.emits('dataPut')    
  }
}
```

So I noticed, I need any starting point. :s

I have had a look into `NodeJS EventErmitter` and found out that the NodeJS Process is also laying on EventErmitter.

I also have had a look into several Tuts for NodeJS Lifecycle Events, but it does not really to help to start the architecture anyway.

I hope, some of you have good references or 'blueprints', which helps me to develope a good core for my node. :)

Have a nice day so far and stay safe!

Greetings

Comment: Nice question, but I'm afraid it's off topic. Stackoverflow isn't intended to give advices or recommend a specific tool, library, method etc. as they are primarily opinion-based and tend to attract spam. Even so, I would suggest you to have a look at NestJS if you're looking for a clean Node architecture.

Comment: Ok thx for the info!

I had a look into NextJS. So that means I have to replace express, right?

Comment: I had a deeper look into NestJS. Looks very interesting so far!

Comment: Yes, Nest uses Express under the hood. It's heavily inspired from Angular's architecture, with modules, controllers, services, dependency injection, decorators etc. Plus it uses Typescript which is awesome